# Is it possible to automatically inject exception handling code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inject

We have a lot of areas of our code base where developers do something like this:

```
try {
   // code 
} catch let error {
   print("error \(error)")
}
```

Console logging the error isn't super helpful, and while it'd be great to do something better, people still do this.

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to add code to the exception handler automatically...ideally by injecting the code at build time.  It'd be purely for tracking, to see what types of errors we're throwing away.

(I know one solution would be to disallow this kind of thing, but we also just want general exception handling to see what types of exceptions are coming up).

Comment: Are you basically asking if there is any way to catch exceptions without explicitly catching exceptions? What's the reason, exactly? You just don't want to have to write catch blocks?

Comment: Just want to automatically have error logs sent to my server instead of being stuck on the devices.

Comment: Sure, but I'm interested in logging handled errors as well as crashes.

Comment: Sorry about that; I thought I was responding to a different question. Disregard my previous bit about PLCrashReporter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to log the error at this point, you can just let the error bubble up by not catching it. Mark the method `throws` and don't put this in a `try` block. Then you can log (or do something else) only at the top level.

Alternately, you can wrap blocks with a function:

```
func trylog(_ f: () throws -> Void) {
    do {
        try f()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Then in `trylog` you could do something else rather than `print` if you like.

Swift `try/catch` aren't really "exceptions." They're just a special syntax around an error-return. That means there's no fancy runtime mechanism to hook into (it'd be very much like hooking into every time `return` is called).

While console logging isn't very helpful because you can't get access to them easily on devices, I'd argue that in almost all cases, "just log it" is exactly the right thing to put in a `catch` block. It is rare that I've encountered a case where there is a more useful thing to do in a mobile app. Devs feel guilty about "just log it," but if you were "doing it right," what exactly would you do? I just recommend replacing your `print` with a more feature-rich logger so you can get some value out of it, or at least wrapping `print` in your own function so you can swap it out later for something better.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  I guess my goal is to automatically log the error so that devs don't have to worry about it.  Basically I'd like to add something that logs these errors, batches them, and sends them to a server analogous to what crashlytics does for unhandled exceptions.

Comment: We can probably just use Crashlytics.shared.recordError(error) everywhere,  I was just thinking it'd be cool to do automatically.

Comment: And, indeed, having a custom `print` or better logger works just as well for this.

Comment: There's no way for devs not to worry about exceptions. If you didn't have to worry about it, it wouldn't be an exception. It is critical that you think about what the correct thing to do in that case is (for example, can you continue through the rest of the function, or must you return?) Your `recordError` idea is exactly right, but I wouldn't do it that way. Create your own function (mine are a variety of functions like `Log.warn` and `Log.assertionFailure`), and have that function (or functions) call Crashlytics. That way you can swap it out for something else later if needed.

Comment: Sorry I meant not having to worry about logging the exception.  I do realize we still would have to worry about the exception itself.  The wrapper is a great idea, thanks.

Comment: Note that `Crashlytics.recordError` only provides you a few records, is expensive to call, and I thought only gave you the information when you have a crash. Personally I send my stuff to Loggly for understanding what kinds of errors occur, and to Crashlytics just to handle crashes. (Expensive to call may not be a huge problem usually, since it's a `catch`, but the devs should be aware if it's possible it'll get called a lot.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up.  We're using Logentries which looks similar to Loggly and is probably a good place as well.